# Snowflake - Failed to rewrite multi-row insert -(insert into select)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I got below error when use the Sqlalchemy to insert the data into Snowflake warehouse, any idea?

***Error***:

Failed to rewrite multi-row insert [SQL: 'INSERT INTO widgets (id, name, type)

SELECT %(id)s AS anon_1, %(name)s AS anon_2, widgets.id \nFROM widgets \nWHERE widgets.type = %(card_id)s']

[parameters: ({'id': 2, 'name': 'Lychee', 'card_id': 1}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'testing', 'card_id': 2})]

***Code***:

```
from sqlalchemy import *

from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL

# Helper function for local debugging
def createSQLAlchemyEngine():
    url = URL(
        account='',
        user='',
        password='',
        database='db',
        schema='',
        warehouse='',
        role='',
        proxy_host='',
        proxy_port=8099
    )
    engine = create_engine(url)
    return engine
conn = createSQLAlchemyEngine()
# Construct database
metadata = MetaData()
widgetTypes = Table('widgetTypes', metadata,
                    Column('id', INTEGER(), nullable=True),
                    Column('type', VARCHAR(), nullable=True))
widgets = Table('widgets', metadata,
                Column('id', INTEGER(), nullable=True),
                Column('name', VARCHAR(), nullable=True),
                Column('type', INTEGER(), nullable=True))
engine = conn
metadata.create_all(engine)
# Connect and populate db for testing
conn = engine.connect()
sel = select([bindparam('id'), bindparam('name'), widgets.c.id]).where(widgets.c.type == bindparam('card_id'))
ins = widgets.insert().from_select(['id', 'name', 'type'], sel)
conn.execute(ins, [
    # {'name': 'Melon',  'type_name': 'Squidgy'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Lychee', 'card_id' : 1 },
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'testing', 'card_id': 2}
])
conn.close()
```

Basically, what Im trying to do this like below, but the Snowflake doesn't support this syntax.

```
insert into  tableXX

values('Z', 

(select max(b) +1 from tableXX a where a.CD = 'I'), 'val1', 'val2')
```

So, I have to do with something like this, but got the above error.

```
insert into tableXX
select 'val1', 'val2', ifnull(max(c), 0) + 1 from tableXX where a.CD = 'I',
select 'val1', 'val2', ifnull(max(c), 0) + 1 from tableXX where a.CD = 'I',
```

**Target:**

The logic behind the code is I want to update the sequence_id base on the max of existing sequence_id of record which has the same 'CD' with the new record.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How did you end up with that query? The reason is that snowflake-connector detects that you are inserting with `executemany` using pyformat placeholders and is trying to rewrite your statement to a single `INSERT ... VALUES ...` "multi values" insert w/o comments [here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/master/cursor.py#L690), but fails (because your statement has no `VALUES` clause).

Comment: @IljaEverilä I have updated my testing code, pls let me know if you have some idea.  Basically, what Im trying to do is to have 'select' subquery in the insert Values statement.

Comment: There's an answer in snowflake community: https://community.snowflake.com/s/feed/0D50Z00009DrGwH (I have asked it right now)