# Snowflake: IFNULL can not be used in the subSQL of INSERT VALUES

Tags: sql-insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ifnull

Got the compilation error when tried to use the IFNULL in the INSERT VALUES clause.

***SQL:***

```
INSERT INTO widgets 
VALUES 
(12, (select ifnull(max(c), 0)+1 from DCSN_Testing where c = 1), 444)
```

***Error***:

```
SQL compilation error: Invalid expression 
[(SELECT (NULLABILITY_EXTERNAL(1)) + 1 AS "IFNULL(MAX(C), 0)+1" 
FROM (VALUES (null)) DCSN_TESTING WHERE TRUE)] in VALUES clause
```

Comment: Currently Snowflake has a limited support for what can be put inside the VALUES clause. The safest is to only put constants there, and use INSERT..SELECT for anything else, like Rich suggested.

Comment: @MarcinZukowski, but this is only for the one row? How about a bunch of records?

Comment: You can always use UNION ALL. I saw your comment about MAX, but it's hard to understand what the problem is. If you provide a full repro case it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: @Marcin Zukowski Please refer the this link for the detail of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55367597/snowflake-failed-to-rewrite-multi-row-insert-insert-into-select

Answer (score 0):

I normally do not have sub-selects inside a VALUES statement of an INSERT, in fact I can't recall doing one in all the years of SQL I've been writing.

That said, I recommend you try the below example of what I'd call "INSERT INTO SELECT" or what Snowflake docs call "Single Row Insert Using a Query", which IMO is a simple/clean way to write the SQL.

Note:  This has been tested on Snowflake.

```
-- this is a simple test table, represents your 
--   DCSN_Testing table, results are a value of 5
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id), 0)+1 FROM first_names;

-- create a test table
DROP TABLE stackoverflow_55387209;
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow_55387209(id NUMBER, 
    new_id NUMBER, other_id  NUMBER);

-- test for your error, results confirm your findings
INSERT INTO stackoverflow_55387209 (id, new_id, other_id)
VALUES (12, (select max(ifnull(id, 0) + 1)  FROM first_names), 444) ;
results:  
SQL compilation error: Invalid expression [(SELECT MAX((NULLABILITY_EXTERNAL(FIRST_NAMES.ID)) + 1) AS "NEW_ID" 
FROM FIRST_NAMES AS FIRST_NAMES)] in VALUES clause

-- rewrite to "INSERT INTO SELECT" type of SQL Query, as described in documentation
--      https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/insert.html#single-row-insert-using-a-query
INSERT INTO stackoverflow_55387209
SELECT 12, MAX(IFNULL(id, 0) + 1), 444  FROM first_names ;
results:  number of rows inserted = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rich Murname. But, the INSERT INTO SELECT only support to insert single row. How about of a bunch of data need to be inserted into the Snowflake? I was trying to do the 'Union ALL' between two SELECT, but unfortunately the 'Max' function get the same value rather than an incremental value.